# Cannot see the annotation on my promotional email

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I am trying to annotate our promotional email - I want to have the image and the voucher code in the preview. I pasted the code as per your instructions here https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview and on the preview it looks as we want to have it. However, when I send the email to myself from our ESP (Dotdigital) it shows as any other email - there is no image showing and no voucher code in the preview. Here is the chunk of html we added to our template in order to annotate. Could you please help us?

Tried multiple test send outs, checked my account settings, created an email address xxxxxxpromotabtesting@gmail.com and tried to send the email there. Nothing worked.

I would like to see the image and discount preview before I actually open the promotional email, however it only shows as a normal email without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your test account on a device with the latest version of the Gmail App? The email with the code is sent direct to the promo tab? You can pull down to refresh what is in the bundle by pulling down on the promo tab screen (can repeat). Also, if the code has an expiration date that hasn't started or is expired, then your email cannot populate in the bundle.

Your ESP may be stripping the script tag - Sometimes there are special instructions (like [add XML into body](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/troubleshooting)). Have you looked at your sent html to make sure the annotation is there and working? Check Show original, copy and paste into [the markup tool](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview) (however if the date is an issue the markup tool will still display all but the expiration date).

The script tag can be added to the head of your email template(s), you can customize the 5 features for the campaign (can be populated with merges or dynamically - should be similar to your current creation process), and then you are all set. For the images, the goal was that you could use the same imagery from the body of your emails (brands have different ways of handling this, such as having a version of the image in the email body made at 538x138). However, all the information for the enriched preview is information already in your email. Mix and match the features to create the best enriched preview to drive your goals (if not using a feature, leave blank).  Source website.

Comment: Thank you so much Heather. It is now sorted and works beautifully :)